# Checking the integrity of an archive uploaded to AWS Glacier

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-glacier

We have daily database backups created and stored on a server. In order to free up space, it was decided that all the backups older than 30 days should be archived using AWS Glacier. 
So far so good, I managed to write a PowerShell script to select the required files and upload them to Glacier, but since I am new to all the AWS stuff, I have one question: is it possible to check that the files I have uploaded are indeed in the archive and that there has been no information loss?

My first approach was to send job retrieval requests for all the files that we have uploaded, and 4 hours later compare the checksums and archive ids of our original files and the ones we retrieved from Glacier. However, I think this process takes long, costs extra money, and most importantly, makes no sense at all..

I have also found that I can use inventory retrieval, but as far as I can tell this approach would be very similar to the one described above, just without downloading all the files again.

Lastly, is there even a point to trying to ensure that a file upload was successful if there are no errors? My vague understanding is that AWS would come back with error messages should an upload to Glacier fail, and it computes checksums internally during uploads.

I know that StackOverflow has seen more precisely worded questions, but any clarification regarding this would be immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to try pretty hard to upload a corrupt file to Glacier, because Glacier requires checksums sent with each API request, and will reject the uploads if they don't match the hashes.  Obviously you need to spot check your archives, but each one does not need to be downloaded and verified because of the built-in protections.

See [Computing Checksums](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/checksum-calculations.html) in the *Amazon S3 Glacier Developer Guide* for descriptions of how this works, on the wire.

Then, consider not using Glacier at all... not directly, anyway.  Use S3, and upload your files using the `GLACIER` or `DEEP_ARCHIVE` storage class.  Or upload them as Standard, with a lifecycle policy that moves them into one of the archive storage classes after 1 day. (Useful because if you delete Glacier or Deep Archive uploads before the minimum storage time, you're billed for the entire minimum time... this way you have a 24 hour "oops I don't like the way I set this up" window, since Standard storage has no minimum storage time period).

Using S3 is a *far* better solution, because S3 has a much better API and console, but the pricing is identical, because S3 is actually using Glacier as its backend, while you have the advantage of S3 as the frontend.  Glacier has essentially no console functionality, is very opaque, and is not really designed for human interaction -- Glacier appears to have been designed as a backing store for an archiving system or service, which is exactly how S3 uses Glacier.

> Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) supports lifecycle configuration on an S3 bucket, which enables you to transition objects to the Amazon S3 GLACIER storage class for archival. When you transition Amazon S3 objects to the GLACIER storage class, Amazon S3 internally uses Glacier for durable storage at lower cost. Although the objects are stored in Glacier, they remain Amazon S3 objects that you manage in Amazon S3, and you cannot access them directly through Glacier.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/introduction.html

It is confusing and unfortunate that AWS recently confused this issue by dumbing things down, rebranding "Glacier" as "S3 Glacier," as if they were the same thing, when they are two very different services, one of which operates in a mode that gives you a gateway to the other.  It's similarly unfortunate how Glacier has traditionally been marketed.  Without S3 in front, Glacier is not well suited for very many  applications.